# Git на хосте пуш правок с одного домена в другой

Tags: git, domain

Добрий день. Скажу сразу, что являюсь новичком в git, поэтому ищу помощи и пошаговую инструкцию. Ситуация такая. Есть рабочий сайт (domen.com), есть субдомен (test.domen.com). Как организовать работу, когда через WinSCP можно вносить и коммитить правки на субдомен (test.domen.com) и, если правки устраивают, пушить эти правки на рабочий сайт (domen.com)?

Comment: Прочитать как работает CI/CD и GitLab в частности. А если хочется без всего этого, то заходим в каталог основного сайта и делаем git pull из того тестового репо.